# Javascript removing <option> from drop-down by id

Tags: javascript, removechild

I am working on an application which dynamically generates a drop-down list of items. IDs generated range from "1" through an integer the user inputs (0 is reserved for a hard coded 'select option'). I want the javascript to dynamically remove options if the user changes their mind and enters a smaller value. Everything up to this point works for the script, but I can't seem to make this work. The following is the section I'm having difficulty with... incidentally the last section before I can build the more interesting parts of my utility.

```
var itemSelect = document.getElementById("itemSelector");
var optionCount = itemSelect.childElementCount;

for (i = optionCount-1, n = arrayTotal.length; i < n; i++)
{
    var itemSelect = document.getElementById("itemSelector");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    var optionCount = itemSelect.childElementCount;
    if (optionCount - 1 > totalItems)
    {
        for (j = optionCount, o = totalItems; o < j; j--)
        {
            var trash = document.getElementById("itemSelector");
            trash.removeChild(trash.childNodes[j]);
        }
    }
    else if (optionCount <= totalItems)
    {
        option.innerHTML = "<option> Item number"+(arrayTotal[i])+"</option>";
        option.value = arrayTotal[i];
        option.id = i;
        itemSelect.appendChild(option);
    }
}
```

I've built a few debug tools to check certain values. arrayTotal[] is correctly receiving items from it's fill function, and dynamically re-sizing as intended. It consistently has the same value as totalItems.

optionCount is correctly populating the drop-down with the maximum value the user inputs, but the section which is supposed to remove extra options if the user enters a smaller value does nothing. I've read lots of similar problems and tried lots of different methods and I am completely at a loss. Is there something specifically wrong about how I am trying to implement this?

Also, is there an obvious reason why not declaring the two variables I do here both outside the "for" loop and inside breaks everything? I'm still new to javascript, but that seems rather odd.

http://jsfiddle.net/CAlbano/s4mzssm1/ is a link to a working fiddle. I've include all the workings for the entire script. The relevant section is near the bottom, but this way you can see what it's doing. The three outputs that run on the canvas element are the value of the last cell of arrayTotal[], the value of totalItems, and the value of optionCount-1. what I want to happen is if optionCount ever becomes larger than totalItems, remove the last child from that list until optionCount == totalItems.

It turned out that I did need to remove the logic for detecting extra options--I just didn't understand what I was being told, and had to learn the hard way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loop condition is

```
...; i < n;...
```

with `i = optionCount-1` and `n = arrayTotal.length`. When the number of array elements is lesser, you never go into the body of your loop (which is where you have your removeChild script.

Comment: That's intended. optionCount - 1 should only ever become less than arrayTotal.length if the user changes it after their initial input. The goal is that this functionality should never be needed, but is a fail-safe against user error

Comment: Could you post your code in a fiddle - it's a bit tricky to guess what's happening. Cheers!

Comment: I've added a fiddle. Link's in the main body.